# What is the fundamental difference between storing the function in a variable in these two ways?

Tags: javascript, function

This is really basic javascript here and probably pretty silly to ask but what is the difference between:

a) function variable(){};
b) var variable = function() {};

I think the second one executes as soon as the browser reads it, am I correct?

Comment: `I think the second one executes as soon as the browser reads it, am I correct?` - no

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is a function statement. The second is a function expression. Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function):

> The main difference between a function expression and a function
>   statement is the function name, which can be omitted in function
>   expressions to create anonymous functions. A function expression can
>   be used as a IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) which runs
>   as soon as it is defined. See also the chapter about functions for
>   more information.